# No module named 'yelpapi' on python 3.8.2

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I have been trying to use YelpAPI for an app and was going through typical API download process, outlined by this website here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-web-apis-in-python-3 and everything was working fine. Then I renamed the folder when adding my code to github and then I started getting an error where I call 
`from yelpapi import YelpAPI` at the top of my code. When I try to run the code, it says that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'yelpapi'`.

My question is how can I fix this? Is there something I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you had the virtual environment active during the module installation, make sure that the it's active when you start the program.

Which folder did you rename? Can you provide the folder structure of the project?
Or better, can you link the GitHub repo if it is public?

There is very little info and while the problem is quite simple, it can have a lot of causes and its hard to say from the given info.

P.S.: While venv is a good tool, when starting out it can cause a lot of beginner problems and confusion, so I recommend that you try doing it without the venv if you can't get a fix.

Comment: Thanks, I stopped using venv and instead just copied filed out of my python/2.7 into my python/3.8 and ended up working.

Answer (score -1):

Add a script called run.py in /home/bodacydo/work/project and edit it like this: import programs. my_python_program programs. my_python_program. main() (replace main() with your equivalent method in my_python_program .)